# Why should I use a docker image repository instead of building from a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker

What is the advantage of storing a docker image somewhere when I could instead give my team my Dockerfile and have them each build the image locally?

Edit: No I won’t reword my question. Its not opinion based. I didn’t ask which is better. I only asked for the justification of images. Thankfully I got good answers before It got closed.

Comment: I guess Gentoo users like this question.

Comment: It once took my Dockerfile 47 minutes to build... Then I pushed it and my team had the new docker image in 2 minutes... I believe 47 minutes is not the limit.

Comment: Sometimes I really not like `primarily opinion-based` option on SO because some of questions are really programmer needed...

Comment: JFC...opinion based.  I clearly wasn’t asking for pros and cons. I asked why should I use a docker image INSTEAD OF a dockerfile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some reasons:

- Building of Dockerfile could be long or computationally exhaustive and so building only once would be beneficial.
- Building of Dockerfile may require specific files/components that only exist on machine A or with person P and so giving a Dockerfile to someone to build just isn't possible without these sources. Or it may be that the Dockerfile contains data not meant to be shown to others (maybe raw passwords as inputs to some commands for example).
- Ensuring no one messes around with the Dockerfile contents, and thus enforcing "repeatability."
- Ease of use. Sometimes as a customer/user you just want to run the image, as opposed to figuring out how to build the thing then run it (thanks for @DazWilkin 's comment).

Comment: Much better answer than mine! :)

Comment: A good answer. I think "Security" is not a valid reason; an image is a zipped file system and anything used by it is accessible to its users. I think perhaps an additional reason is that, images are primarily for distribution to customers|users and generally (!?) this audience wants to just run (not build) solutions. For distribution, the image manifest's hash (digest) can be provided for strong assurance that the image has not been tampered with.

Comment: @DazWilkin ,thanks. Will update with your points shortly. Question first, if I had a line in the Dockerfile, like : `RUN curl --insecure --user username:password -T /path/to/sourcefile sftp://desthost/path/` where the raw password and username are passed as part of the command. Can this information be found within the image?

Comment: Ah, no it would not. I see your point. Perhaps include that under "Building..."

Comment: @DazWilkin , sure.

Answer (score 2):

Building a docker image can take a while. It can also fail for network reasons (as can pulling a docker image from a repository).

But one of the key advantages of using an existing image is the same advantage for using any cache of stable, unchanging data. If you don't want to take any changes, why rebuild it? I use docker images for my build environments; these are something I only want to rebuild when I upgrade my build environments. There is a performance cost to doing that.